# Flask/Pymongo Where/How do I apply validation?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, validation, flask, pymongo

This does not seem to apply validation to the collection. No exceptions are thrown and documents can have attributes of the wrong type. Perhaps I am doing it in the wrong section of the codebase? Right now it is in __init__.py

__init__.py

```
db = database(client, settings.mongo_db_name)

from api.models import Company
validation_level = 'strict'

if 'companies' not in db.collection_names():                                        
  db.create_collection('companies', validator=Company.validator, validationLevel=validation_level)
else:                                                                               
  db.command({                                                                      
    'collMod': 'companies',                                                         
    'validator': Company.validator,                                                 
    'validationLevel': validation_level,                                            
  })
```

Company Model:

```
from api import db

class Company(Model):                                                               
  collection = db.companies
  validator = {                                                                     
    '$jsonSchema': {                                                                
      'bsonType': 'object',                                                         
      'required': ['name', 'description'],                                          
      'properties': {                                                               
        'logo': {                                                                   
          'bsonType': 'string',                                                     
        },                                                                          
        'name': {                                                                   
          'bsonType': 'string',                                                     
          'description': 'name of company is required',                             
          'minLength': 4,                                                           
        },                                                                          
        'description': {                                                            
          'bsonType': 'string',                                                     
          'description': 'description of company is required',                      
          'minLength': 4,                                                           
        },                                                                          
        'website': {                                                                
          'bsonType': 'string',                                                     
        },                                                                          
        'request_delete': {                                                         
          'bsonType': 'bool',                                                       
        },                                                                          
        'deleted': {                                                                
          'bsonType': 'bool',                                                       
        },                                                                          
      }                                                                             
    }                                                                               
  }
```

[As discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575901/1559782), I also tried this without success:

```
db.command(OrderedDict([                                                         
  ('collMod', 'companies'),                                                      
  ('validator', Company.validator),                                              
  ('validationLevel', validation_level),                                         
]))
```

If this were successful, would I see validation rules when running the following command?

```
pprint(db.command('collstats', 'companies'))
```

### Update

I added OrderedDict to both command arguments and the validator. This works... when I run specific tests. It does not work with

```
python -m unittest discover
```

I'm using Python 3.6.8, PyMongo 3.8.0, and MongoDB 3.6.3

Comment: This is a guess, but maybe the validation is being applied to the first run test and none of the others? That kind of leads me back to my original question.

Comment: When you say "... It does not work ..." what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's better to validate a document BEFORE inserting it to the database. In this case, you'll omit errors in schema

Comment: Well, that's kind of [what Mongo does do](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). If you set the `validationLevel` to Error, it won't insert the object(s) unless the validation is passed.